# Is it usually best to compile on the same machine you want to execute on?

Tags: packages, compile, build

(Note: I'm just using `ffmpeg` as an example, I have often wondered the same thing with other programs)

I have a build script for `ffmpeg` which compiles in support for a few non-standard features.  Now I want to use that encoder on several other machines.  Is it OK just to copy the `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` executable over, or should I prefer to run the build script on the other machines?

- Are there likely to be any hardware-dependent optimisations in the compilation?
- Is it possible to have any hidden dependencies which I also need to copy, apart from the executable itself and anything I can find with `ldd`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes and yes :)

if you want your compiled binary to run on a number of machines, you have to compile it in a way that it matches the architecture and setup (library-wise) on these machines. that normally means:

- link everything you can statically
- ship the libs your binary needs
- 32bit stuff runs on 64bit machines, but not the other way around

so, if you do not want to think about if it might run or if it wont: compile and link the binary on the machine you want it to run.